# Is there a Kli Yakar on Nach

Tags: navi-prophets

I've heard ideas from the Keli Yakar before. Did he write a commentary on the Navi?

I have only seen his commentary on the Chumash, at least as far as I recall.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be from his Wikipedia page.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88864/16354 is from another keli yakar on nach, not the one who wrote the commentary on the Torah

Comment: @רבותמחשבות https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.20.15

Comment: @DoubleAA when you are right, you are right

Comment: @רבותמחשבות and when i'm a tautology, i'm a tautology.

Comment: @DoubleAA *eyeroll*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He did not write a commentary on Nach.

Comment: I would add like you said, that there is a different kli yakar on nach. I believe he was a student of Rav Shlomo alkabetz. I quote it [here](https://parshaponders.com/shemini-5778/#_ftn9), coincidentally from parshas shemini.

Comment: When I wrote "like you said", I meant in that comment

Comment: @robev missed that, sorry.